# Android ListActivity - how to add a view below the ListView?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview

I'm trying to put a ProgressBar view below a ListView for a ListActivity. I want it to be always below the last row in the listView.

The ProgressBar, which is placed in a LinearLayout, does appear, as long as the list (which is filled by an adapter at runtime) is not exceeding the screen. As soon as the list is larger than the screen, the ProgressBar is no longer visible.

The layout xml looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/db1_root"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

<!-- Title bar -->
<LinearLayout
    style="@style/TitleBar" >
    <TextView
        style="@style/TitleBarText"
        android:text="Some title text" />
    <ImageButton
        style="@style/TitleBarAction"
        android:contentDescription="@string/description_search"
        android:src="@drawable/title_search" />
</LinearLayout>

<!--  Content -->
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" >

    <ListView
        android:divider="@drawable/category_item_divider"
        android:dividerHeight="@dimen/list_divider_height"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/android:list"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1" />        
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/android:empty"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:text="@string/category_no_items" />                 
</LinearLayout>     

<!--  Progress bar -->
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" >

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/productlist_progressbar"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</LinearLayout> 

</LinearLayout>
```

Is this not possible with a LinearLayout? Any help appreciated.

Comment: Footers scroll with the listview, if you want the view to be fixed on the bottom on the screen, below listview, set weigth on the listview

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You should add a footer using :

```
list.addFooterView(footerView);
```

or doing it manually, but then consider using relative layouts, there are far more powerfull than linear layouts. And then place your footer below the list, or better, place your list *and* your empty view above your footerview.

Comment: Thanks, the footer view is exactly what I was looking for. The only small issue I have now is that I've set a android:divider in my ListView, and when I set the footerView to visibility=GONE (it's only used when loading more data), I have two dividers at the bottom. Guess there's no "fix" for that :-)