# How to add view below listview

Tags: java, android, listview

I found few topics here on SO, but they are not what i'm searching. One of them is this one [Android ListActivity - how to add a view below the ListView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6190820/android-listactivity-how-to-add-a-view-below-the-listview)

I know i can position a View (like button) at the footer of listview. That means desired View will position itself AFTER last view.

I want to know how to position a View at the end of the screen (Just below). 
Please check two pictures below:

[image]

[image]

I want to do this in java code. Any ideas?

Comment: Should the button below the last item in the list (for example you have to scroll down to see it) or just below the listview? I hope you understand what i mean.

Comment: below the listview. so if preferences are too big to fit entire screen it should scroll below to get to the button. But if not , it should be in like second picture.

Comment: oh. what about fixed size? Button is there fixed at bottom and preferences can still scroll up/down?

Comment: Sorry got it wrong. In your case it could be easier.

Answer (score 1):

try the following code

```
<ListView
    android:id="@android:id/list"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/button1"
     >

</ListView>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:text="Button" />
```

Comment: This should be done in java code. Because i have preference screen..(im adding content with : addpreferencesfromresource

Answer (score 1):

Use a Relative Layout. Set the Height of Listview to the required height. Place the button relative to the listview at the button.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"

tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:text="TextView" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="122dp"
    android:text="Button" />

 </RelativeLayout>
```